# MariaDB 10 dont recognize JSON_* functions

Tags: jquery, mysql, mariadb

For some reason i cant do JSON_* select functions, not sure why this is happening, for example, if i run the query below i got the error

```
select * FROM mytable WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(mycolumn, JSON_QUOTE('2'),"$.edit.element");

[Err] 1305 - FUNCTION dbname.JSON_CONTAINS does not exist
```

this is the first time i'm using this, and seemed to be a good aproach to reach the requeriments of my project, but not sure if im missing something, any help?

This is the mariaDB version im using

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB supports JSON functions starting from the version **10.2.3**:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json-functions/